# c#.net Replace plain text on html string with start given index and length

Tags: html, .net, replace

Let's say, given html string below:

```
<b>The quick <span>bro</span>wn fox jump over the lazy dog</b>
```

And the data I have now are:

1. Start Index of the text that I want to replace (Start Index = 11)
2. Length of the the text (Length = 5)
3. And the replace text that i want to replace with (Replace Text = "yellow")

And make the final result become:

```
<b>The quick <span>yellow</span> fox jump over the lazy dog</b>
```

Basically what I can think of would be chop each characters down into a list,
and then use flag to determine if the character is HTML begin / end tag. if not then replace it by each character. Append the remaining character if the length already over. If the original text is shorter than the replace text then we will remove the remaining character until the length has reached.

Any one have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Read that string like it is XML and add the value related to each node into a list, then find the word you want to replace by adding the count of each word in the list until you reach your Start Index (you can stop even in the middle of a word, for example: "the", "quick", "brown" has 3 words, let's say you want to start by position 5. The first word has its count less than 5, so you can move on, and see the first word's count + the second word's count is 8, which is greater than 5, so you need to stop at the second word. The first character to be replaced in the second word is your start index minus the total count before the second word, in this case is 5-3 = 2, so the 2nd character in the second word is the first one to be replaced. If your word is longer than the remaining characters you need to replace in next word(s), until you reach your Length). After replacing the word just build again the string with the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the unit tests that i wrote:
It will use a "delete" and then "insert" approach.
So basically it can covered some cases like replacing a text between 2 different nodes.
And handle chinese wording or special characters.

Does anyone has a better approach?

```
[TestCase(@"<b>The quick <span>bro</span>wn fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", "<b>The quick <span>yellow</span> fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", 10, 5, "yellow", TestName = "Find_And_Replace 1")]
    [TestCase(@"<b>The <span>quick</span> <span>bro</span>wn fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", "<b>The <span>quick</span> <span>yellow</span> fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", 10, 5, "yellow", TestName = "Find_And_Replace 2")]
    [TestCase(@"<b>The quick brown &amp; yellow tiger fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", @"<b>The quick brown &amp; yellow croco fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", 25, 5, "croco", TestName = "Find_And_Replace 3")]
    [TestCase(@"<div style=""text-align: left;""><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">The </span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">快快的</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';""> brown fox jump over the lazy dog</span></div>", @"<div style=""text-align: left;""><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">The </span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">快快的</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';""> brown fox bend under the lazy dog</span></div>", 18, 9, "bend under", TestName = "Find_And_Replace 4")]
    [TestCase(@"<b>The quick <span>bro</span>wn fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", "<b>The quick <span>red</span> fox jump over the lazy dog</b>", 10, 5, "red", TestName = "Find_And_Replace 5")]
    [TestCase(@"<div style = ""text-align: left;"" >< span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">The quick</span><span style = ""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri'; font-weight: bold;"" > brown &#38; sl</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">ow tort</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri'; text-decoration: underline;"" data-underline-style=""single"">oise jump</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';""> over the lazy dog</span></div>", @"<div style = ""text-align: left;"" >< span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';"">The quick</span><span style = ""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri'; font-weight: bold;"" > brown or fat pig</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';""></span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri'; text-decoration: underline;"" data-underline-style=""single""> jump</span><span style=""font-size: 11pt; font-family: 'Calibri';""> over the lazy dog</span></div>", 16, 15, "or fat pig", TestName = "Find_And_Replace 6")]

    public void Find_And_Replace(string originalParagraphText, string expected, int startIndex, int length, string replaceText)
    {
        var insideHtmlTag = false;
        var insideSpecialCharacter = false;

        var currentIndex = 0;
        var foundStartRawIndex = 0;
        var currentRawIndex = 0;
        var isFound = false;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var character in originalParagraphText.ToCharArray())
        {
            var appendIntoNewHtml = true;

            if (character == '<')
            {
                insideHtmlTag = true;
            }

            if (!insideHtmlTag)
            {
                if (currentIndex >= startIndex && currentIndex < (startIndex + length))
                {
                    if (!isFound)
                    {
                        foundStartRawIndex = currentRawIndex;
                        isFound = true;
                    }

                    appendIntoNewHtml = false;
                }

                if (character == '&')
                {
                    insideSpecialCharacter = true;
                }
                else if (insideSpecialCharacter && character == ';')
                {
                    insideSpecialCharacter = false;
                }

                if (!insideSpecialCharacter)
                {
                    currentIndex++;
                }
            }

            if (character == '>')
            {
                insideHtmlTag = false;
            }

            if (appendIntoNewHtml)
            {
                sb.Append(character);
            }

            currentRawIndex++;
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        var actual = sb.Insert(foundStartRawIndex, replaceText).ToString();
        //Console.WriteLine($@"Current Found Raw Index: {foundStartRawIndex}");
        //Console.WriteLine($@"Replace Text : {actual}");

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```